# Some problems while operating with a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logarithm

I have a Dataframe with some values sorted by date and NaN if I don't have a value for a certain item on a date. For each value, I want to replace it with the log of that value minus the log of the first not the NaN value in the column. I have written the following code:

```
for x in AntCris.columns:
  aux=AntCris[x].dropna()
  aux2=aux.iloc[0]
  for y in AntCris[x].values:
    if np.isnan(y)==True:
      b=2
    else:
      a=np.log(y)-np.log(aux2)
      AntCris[x]=AntCris[x].replace([y],a)
```

I know it is not very efficient, I'm a bloody beginner. The point is that the dataframe looks like this before operating[image]
But after executing the code, I get that the first non-NaN value for 'Oro' and 'Bonos' becomes -inf as if it was the logarithm of 0, but it is not. I have no idea how I could solve it or even why is this happening.

I'm also receiving this output warning: `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log`. I know they happen in the columns 'Oro' and 'SP500' as I wrote `print(x)` in each operation, but I would like to know the exact index or some information so I can check what is happening. How could I do this?

Comment: Did you check the datatype you receive in your log() function? Maybe there are some unexpected types inside your dataframe. Try a if condition if the y or aux2 == 0 print("error")  else do you log calculations

Comment: Thank you! I added `if aux2==0 or y==0: print('error')`else do the log calculations. With that change the 'error' is printed twice and, as the log calculus are not done for those values, the -inf are now 0, but I still don't understand when are them set to zero.

Comment: I think the problem might lie within your column-wise dropna() approach. Considering this to be one big dataframe, droping empty rows for each column results in columns of different length, which you try to fill later again? Therfore i suggest droping your nas before iterating? Maybe using the subset=[] parameter to further specify what columns you want to drop the nas from.